# paleolithic boot in modern hardware

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb

I needed to run a DOS utility to scan a malfunctioning hard drive.  The laptop had no floppy drive, so I downloaded a win98se boot iso.  It booted just fine but once booted it could not see the CD that it had just booted from.  The boot CD has cdrom drivers but apparently none work with  modern hardware.  Also, it could not access himem to install its ram drive.  And so I could never access the dos utility.

Now, the specific problem was finally solved by booting a USB drive.  Still, are there drivers I could put on the boot cd to give me a usable machine?  I have an iso editor, I just don't know what to add.

-----Paul-----

Comment: Just curious: why can't you work with modern tools and spare yourself a trouble? The hardware is too old or what?

Comment: Modern tools??  We're talking Win98SE here, the supreme version of windows ever created!  Well, at least until Win7 came out.  And Win7 doesn't provide a boot disk.  The fact is that this has gone from 'trying to solve a real world problem' to 'there must be some way to turn this stone axe into a battery powered drill'.  Just thought someone might already have the answer.

Comment: I meant modern tools to scan a HDD. I was just curious what was the reason to choose a DOS utility over (probably) less troublesome modern ones.

Comment: It was Spinrite.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.freedos.org/. It is an open-source DOS system and includes "CD-ROM support with XCDROM and SHSUCDX (similar to MSCDEX)"

Comment: The dos utility I was trying to run came with freedos.  It encountered an unusual error and it was posited that some disk controllers had allergies to freedos and I should try the win98boot thing.